# AngularJS ngTable delays display of ajax data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html, angularjs

### Background

I am struggling with the finer points of using [ngTable](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table).  I went through the [ngTable ajax demo](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6) and tried to follow the example as reasonably as possible; however, I need to deviate from the part where the [ngTable ajax demo](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6) defines an [ngResource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) inline with the Controller.

### Problem

I successfully built an [ngTable](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) with [ngTable filters](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/4); My webapp is **[here](http://demo.pennington.net/)** (also see the **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQuZOn)**).  This is an ngTable which:

- Loads data from a [json REST service](http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01)
- Builds the [ngTable](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) from the json data
- Sorts
- Filters

The [json REST service](http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01) loads correctly, and the filters work.  However, my problem is that the table is blank until I type something in the Filter field (see the [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdaUi.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTRnt.png) screenshots below).

The problem exists with all browsers I have tried:

- Firefox 27.0.1 (Windows Vista)
- Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 (Windows Vista)
- Chrome Version 32.0.1700.123 (Linux - Debian 7.0 Wheezy)

I know the webapp is broken in Internet Exploder 9... I don't know why, but I really don't care about IE; this webapp is not going to be a public web service.

### Questions

- How do I make the table populate the first time I load [my webapp](http://demo.pennington.net/) (without typing anything in the filter boxes)?
- Why is this broken now?

*Note*: The source code is at the bottom of the page... I built a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQuZOn)** for it.

---

**End Notes**

<sup>**Note 1**</sup><sub>*Sharp-eyed readers may notice that I'm using `[[` and `]]` in my [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) form instead of the default curly-brace delimiters.  I did this because I'm using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) with [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) (which also needs double curly-braces for its templating engine).*.</sub>

---

**Screen shots**

*BEFORE: Page is blank when I load it*:

[image: blank ngTable]

*AFTER: However, if I type any character in the filters, the [ngTable](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) displays the data*:

[image: ngTable with filter]

---

### Update: Explicit Problem Resolution, thanks to lib3d's answer

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    "use strict";
    // Set up an ngResource service to make HTTP GET / POST / DELETE calls
    var Api = angular.module("api_main", ["ngResource"]);
    Api.factory("restDemo", function ($resource) {
        // http://www.masnun.com/2013/08/28/rest-access-in-angularjs-using-ngresource.html
        return $resource("http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01", {}, {});
    });

    // Loosely based on this ngTable demo...
    //       http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6
    var App2 = angular.module('taskTable', ['ngRoute', 'api_main', 
        'ngTable']);
    // Need to change AngularJS symbols when using flask + Jinja
    App2.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    });

    App2.controller('tableCntl', function($scope, $filter, restDemo, ngTableParams) {


        var data = restDemo.query(); // HTTP GET for REST service


        // Set up task table parameters
        /* Lib3d's fix (i.e. data.$promise) is below */
        data.$promise.then(function (data) {
            /* the data is here, work with it */
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10,          // count per page
                total: data.length,
                sorting: {
                    Column01: 'asc',
                    Column02: 'asc',
                    Column03: 'asc'
                },
                filter: {
                    Column01: "",
                    Column02: "",
                    Column03: "",
                }
            }, {
                getData: function($defer, params) {

                    // Filtering
                    var orderedData = params.filter() ?
                           $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
                           data;

                    // Sorting
                    orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                        $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) :
                        orderedData;
                   $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(),  params.page() * params.count()));

                    /* set total for recalc pagination */
                    params.total(orderedData.length);

                    // This shouldn't be required, but keeping here in case
                    //if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                    //    $scope.$apply();
                    //}
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

*The broken demo source code*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.4.2/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ngtable/0.3.1/ng-table.css">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 30px; /* 30px pad at the top of screen */
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Fix up title -->
    <title>DATA DEMO</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pure-g">
    </div>
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <div class="pure-g">
      <div id="menu" class="pure-u">
        <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-open">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Add Demo</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">List Demo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List Projects</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/login">Login</a>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--- insert stuff here -->
  <div id="Tasks" ng-app="taskTable" ng-controller="tableCntl">
    <p><strong>Filter:</strong> [[tableParams.filter()|json]]
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="words in $data">
              <td data-title="'Column01'" sortable="Column01" filter="{'Column01': 'text'}">
                  [[words.Column01]]
              </td>
              <td data-title="'Column02'" sortable="Column02" filter="{'Column02': 'text'}">
                  [[words.Column02]]
              </td>
              <td data-title="'Column03'" sortable="Column03" filter="{'Column03': 'text'}">
                  [[words.Column03]]
              </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </body>
  <!-- insert JS at the bottom of the page -->
  <footer>
    <!-- all flash messages are processed here -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ngtable/0.3.1/ng-table.js"></script>
    <!--
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        "use strict";
        // Set up an ngResource service to make HTTP GET / POST / DELETE calls
        var Api = angular.module("api_main", ["ngResource"]);
        Api.factory("restDemo", function ($resource) {
            // http://www.masnun.com/2013/08/28/rest-access-in-angularjs-using-ngresource.html
            return $resource("http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01", {}, {});
        });

        // Loosely based on this ngTable demo...
        //       http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6
        var App2 = angular.module('taskTable', ['ngRoute', 'api_main', 
            'ngTable']);
        // Need to change AngularJS symbols when using flask + Jinja
        App2.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
        });

        App2.controller('tableCntl', function($scope, $filter, restDemo, ngTableParams) {


            var data = restDemo.query(); // HTTP GET for REST service
            // Set up task table parameters
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10,          // count per page
                total: data.length,
                sorting: {
                    Column01: 'asc',
                    Column02: 'asc',
                    Column03: 'asc'
                },
                filter: {
                    Column01: "",
                    Column02: "",
                    Column03: "",
                }
            }, {
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    // use build-in angular filter
                    var orderedData = params.filter() ?
                           $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
                           data;

                    //sorting
                    orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                        $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) :
                        orderedData;

                    // store filtered data as $scope.words
                    $scope.words = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                    $defer.resolve($scope.words);
                    $defer.resolve(data.result);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Custom footer content here -->

  </footer>
</html>
```

---

*The data (I will delete the demo [json REST service](http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01) after the question is answered)*:

```javascript
[{"Column02": "shines", "Column03": "paycheck", "Column01": "days"}, 
 {"Column02": "erg", "Column03": "gag", "Column01": "emotion's"}, 
 {"Column02": "Chris", "Column03": "Poznan's", "Column01": "treasure's"}, 
 {"Column02": "presentiments", "Column03": "Austerlitz's", "Column01": "suppression's"}, 
 {"Column02": "leopards", "Column03": "slosh's", "Column01": "upturned"}, 
 {"Column02": "uncaring", "Column03": "cosmetics", "Column01": "symmetry"}, 
 {"Column02": "guesser's", "Column03": "lapped", "Column01": "retrogressed"},
 {"Column02": "Kurd", "Column03": "wryest", "Column01": "cicadas"}, 
 {"Column02": "cantered", "Column03": "encrustation's", "Column01": "beyond"}, 
 {"Column02": "flybys", "Column03": "poesying", "Column01": "physician's"}, 
 {"Column02": "fun", "Column03": "Delaware's", "Column01": "destructiveness"}, 
 {"Column02": "scramblers", "Column03": "gestates", "Column01": "acoustics"}, 
 {"Column02": "redesigning", "Column03": "cubits", "Column01": "Enterprise"}, 
 {"Column02": "phonograph's", "Column03": "haloed", "Column01": "upsurge"}, 
 {"Column02": "Michelson", "Column03": "Pansy", "Column01": "McCoys"}, 
 {"Column02": "adieu", "Column03": "Dido", "Column01": "ligaturing"}, 
 {"Column02": "osprey's", "Column03": "expressiveness's", "Column01": "Starr"}, 
 {"Column02": "patent's", "Column03": "therapeutically", "Column01": "brasher"}, 
 {"Column02": "enfranchise", "Column03": "idolized", "Column01": "criticized"}, 
 {"Column02": "Angel", "Column03": "wryest", "Column01": "drum"}, 
 {"Column02": "overstaying", "Column03": "tranquillized", "Column01": "alacrity"}, 
 {"Column02": "underachievers", "Column03": "minority", "Column01": "Brigham's"}, 
 {"Column02": "lobotomy's", "Column03": "filament's", "Column01": "scoldings"}, 
 {"Column02": "original", "Column03": "muskmelon's", "Column01": "financially"}, 
 {"Column02": "flagon's", "Column03": "vapidness", "Column01": "Klaus's"}, 
 {"Column02": "dhotis", "Column03": "fleeter", "Column01": "jugulars"}, 
 {"Column02": "shanty", "Column03": "profiteer's", "Column01": "disbelief"}, 
 {"Column02": "bureaucracies", "Column03": "flashier", "Column01": "refrigerating"}, 
 {"Column02": "betrayal's", "Column03": "hindquarters", "Column01": "faze"}, 
 {"Column02": "Poland", "Column03": "cobbler", "Column01": "kidnaped"}]
```

---

**I'm using...**

- [Yahoo PureCSS](http://purecss.io/) version 0.4.2
- jQuery version 2.0.3
- [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) version 1.2.14<sup>Note 1</sup>

**What I already tried**

None of these things seemed to have an effect on the problem:

- Remove jQuery
- Remove [Yahoo PureCSS](http://purecss.io/)
- Change default values on the [ngTable Filters](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/4)
- Remove all other javascript from the page (this actually had multiple [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) controllers on the same page, but removed all others in hopes that it was just a simple script conflict.
- Several experimental *what-if-I-modify-this* (read: grasping at straws) in the AngularJS controller which builds the ngTable.
- Tried using `null` instead of empty strings in my filter, as [suggested by Sander Elias](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/r50jwoUKsfU/4PwGJ_t__WQJ)

If I inline the json data inside the `<script>` block instead of making an ajax [json REST service](http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01) call, the table populates correctly when the page loads, but that really doesn't help since the data changes from time to time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `data` are asynchronously fetched but you use it synchronously. Then first `getData` call uses unresolved data, which means no data at all.

Typing a character seems to recall `getData` with, this time, resolved `data`. That would explain data showing on first key typed.

To wait for data being fetched, implement `ngTable` call in such a callback:

```
/* there, data are not fetched */
data.$promise.then(function (data) {
    /* there data are fetched, work with it */
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. The only magic that was happening with such asynchronous data is that when used in templates, the promise was unwrapped at resolve time. As of version 1.2.0-rc.3, you have to add this config: `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)`. But before unwrapping, no magic happen !