# AngularJS + ngTable + plunker will not render table correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, plunker

#### Bakground

I have a bit of a chicken and egg problem:

- I built a *[demo webapp](http://demo.pennington.net/)* to illustrate [a challenging problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22429534/667301) I have with AngularJS + ngTables; however, my webserver logs tell me that nobody really cares about my [demo webapp](http://demo.pennington.net/), they only want a plunker.
- I even built a *[demo webapp plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQuZOn)*; however, the plunker behaves differently than my [demo webapp](http://demo.pennington.net/).  Thus, this question.

#### Question

Please help me understand why:

- My [demo webapp](http://demo.pennington.net/) renders the ngTable from [json data](http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01), if you type a character in the search box.
- The [demo webapp plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQuZOn) refuses to render the [json data](http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01) at all

I realize plunkers are popular; however, the [demo webapp plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQuZOn) is not helping because I can't get it to behave as my webapp does; I literally copied the HTML straight off my [demo webapp](http://demo.pennington.net/) into [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQuZOn).  Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but I need help understanding what I've done wrong (if anything).

**Explicit resolution**

I'm using Flask + Python to render the [json data](http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01)... the explicit fix was...

```python
from functools import update_wrapper
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from json import dumps

from flask import Response, Flask, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
## Other imports here...

def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None,
                max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True,
                automatic_options=True):
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers

            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator

### Use @crossdomain() decorator to fix my plunker's ajax request
@app.route('/demo/api/v1/data01', methods=['GET'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
#@login_required
def send_all_tasks():
    """Send all tasks back to AngularJS"""
    retval = [
        {'Column02': 'shines', 'Column03': 'paycheck', 'Column01': 'days'},
        {'Column02': 'erg', 'Column03': 'gag', 'Column01': "emotion's"},
        ]
    return Response(dumps(retval), mimetype='application/json')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). If you check the console in your plunkr, you will see that the ajax request for your json is failing with the following error...

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://demo.pennington.net/demo/api/v1/data01. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.
```

By default, only pages served by your domain (demo.pennington.net) can make ajax calls to your domain. This is for security purposes. You can configure your server to allow requests from plunkr.co by setting an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header with the value of plunkr.co like the error message states, however this would allow anyone who creates a plunkr to send ajax requests to your site. This is not very secure. If I were you, I would just hardcode the json in your plunkr and remove the ajax request.

Comment: Thank you; I'm actually a network engineer, not a web developer so this problem escaped me.  Actually I'm not sure I care whether someone sends ajax requests to that site, since  the only authorized action is a GET, and this is the only active uri... no?

Comment: Fancy little web dev demo for a network engineer :) In that case, you could just set the header to * to allow all domains

Comment: The security feature is to prevent me from downloading a packet sniffer, sniffing my neighbors un-protected wifi network and getting his facebook authentication token and then sending authenticated requests from my local machine (or a plunkr) and reading all his juicy facebook messages. In this case, sounds like you have nothing to protect, so I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: RE: fancy webapp... I guess I'm a glutton for punishment... this has been a non-stop headache from the beginning :)... if you have some hints for [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429534/angularjs-ngtable-delays-display-of-ajax-data) feel free to chime in on that